# Dll become unable to load when calling function from another dll

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine

Now I have a Unity (C#) project, which calls my C++ project from a dll. They both worked fine, so as calling C++ functions from Unity.

However, when I try add **one line** to call a function another library (NLOpt library, from another dll) in the C++ project, the generated dll becomes unable to be loaded in the Unity project.

**Plugin.h**

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool __stdcall LoadData(int agent_num, int frame_num, float* data);
```

**Plugin.cpp**

```
#include "Plugin.h"
#include <nlopt.h>
__declspec(dllexport) bool __stdcall LoadData(int agent_num, int frame_num, float* d)
{
    ...
    nlopt_opt opt = nlopt_create(NLOPT_LN_COBYLA, 3); //this line
}
```

As I add the line above, Unity will the following error:

```
Plugins: Failed to load 'Assets/Plugins/BirdOpti/BirdOpti.dll'
```

and

```
DllNotFoundException: Opti
```

I have tried couple of times so I am sure the problem is the line.

Did I do anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding also the used dll file to the plugin directory solves the problem.